# Attribute Error in a class - python - on pycharm

Tags: python

Following is the error

**pygame 2.0.0 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.7.7)**

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:/Users/T######/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/env.py", line 54, in < module >
>    game_over, score = game.play_step()
>  File "C:/Users/T######/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/env.py", line 46, in play_step
>    return game_over, self.score
> AttributeError: 'SpaceInvaders' object has no attribute 'score'**
> ```

In class `SpaceInvaders`, it has score attribute though -

```py
class SpaceInvaders:

    def __int__(self, w=640, h=480):

        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        # init display
        self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((self.w, self.h))
        pygame.display.set_caption("SpaceInvaders")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        # init game state
        self.direction = Direction.RIGHT

        self.head = Point[self.w/2, self.h/2]
        self.score = 0
    
    def play_step(self):
        game_over = False
        return game_over, self.score
```

any solution to this problem?

Comment: It is a typo. `__int__` should be `__init__`. This question is not useful for others. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `__init__` and not `__int__`.
so your code should look like this:

```py
def __init__(self, w=640, h=480):
    ...
    self.score = 0
```